# Remove multiple namespaces from XML with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

My XML having multiple namespaces. I want clean XML just with tags only. Here is my XML:

```
    <BizMsg xmlns="urn:asx:xsd:xasx.802.001.04" xmlns:xsi_0="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi_0:schemaLocation="urn:asx:xsd:xasx.802.001.04 ASX_AU_CHS_comm_802_001_04_xasx_802_001_04.xsd">
      <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02" xmlns:xsi_1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi_1:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02 ASX_AU_CHS_comm_801_001_02_head_001_001_02.xsd">
            <From>
            </From>
       </AppHdr>
  </BizMsg>
```

I am able to remove `xmlns` with this code:

```
public static XElement RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement e)
        {
            return new XElement(e.Name.LocalName,
               (from n in e.Nodes()
                select ((n is XElement) ? RemoveAllNamespaces(n as XElement) : n)),
               (e.HasAttributes) ? (from a in e.Attributes()
                                    where (!a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                                    select new XAttribute(a.Name.LocalName, a.Value)) : null);
        }
```

By applying this code I am getting `schemaLocation` in result, I want to get just tag only as result. Please advise.

```
    <BizMsg schemaLocation="urn:asx:xsd:xasx.802.001.04 ASX_AU_CHS_comm_802_001_04_xasx_802_001_04.xsd">
      <AppHdr schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02 ASX_AU_CHS_comm_801_001_02_head_001_001_02.xsd">
       <From>
       </From>
     </AppHdr>
   </BizMsg>
```

I want to get as result:

```
   <BizMsg>
      <AppHdr>
       <From>
       </From>
     </AppHdr>
   </BizMsg>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add desired output.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky added output.

Comment: Are you open to use XSLT?

Comment: If I can get the required output than it's okay to use.

Comment: Why do you want to remove XML namespaces?  Your reference to "clean" XML (namespaces are not "unclean"), your confusion between namespaces and `schemaLocation` attributes, and your lack of any justifying motivation suggest that obliging your request may do more harm than good.  XML namespaces play an important role in identifying XML components and should not be removed without understanding that role fully.

Comment: @kjhughes I agree, but I want to do some Integration and I can do that only by removing namespaces.

Comment: See duplicate links for how to do it all in
 XSLT as @YitzhakKhabinsky suggests, or how to remove namespaces and how to remove attributes (`schemaLocation`) in C# as the question is tagged.